# Making the Smallest Number of Mistakes Possible

Tags: geometry, optimization, convex-optimization, pattern-recognition

I have the following problem. I have a set of $k$ labelled points, $\left\{\mathbf{x}_i, y_i\right\}_{i=1}^{k}$, where $\mathbf{x}_i\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, and $y_i\in\left\{-1,1\right\}$.

I want to find the minimum possible number of misclassifications that can be made by using a straight line as the classifier.

If the points are [linearly separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability), this should obviously be $0$, and it can be at most equal to $k$ (e.g. if the points are linearly separable and one picks the right line but the wrong sides, which should never be the case, but it's just an upper bound).

I have no preference as to how the line is drawn - in fact, I don't even care about the line at all.

I have considered using a [Support Vector Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), but at first sight it seems like it may be an overkill for what I need (especially because one needs to select additional parameters, like $C$, and I don't think that this is at all necessary given my problem description). Is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the points on a circle
with $y$ values alternating
0 and 1.

Then any linear classifier
will have about 1/2 its answers
incorrect.

Comment: @marty_cohen Sorry, maybe I have not been clear in asking my question, but thanks for the answer. This is not what I'm after. I want a method to extract the minimum possible number of misclassifications *given any particular set of labelled points*.